# How to run a csh script to install f2c?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, scripts, csh

I need to install f2c in Linux. Given the steps;

1. Download installation script : Download `install_f2c_linux.csh`.
2. Run installation script

   ```
   # chmod +x install_f2c_linux.csh
   # ./install_f2c_linux.csh
   ```

I run the second step in the root and user directory. But, it says

```
curl: Command not found.
tar: f2c.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
gunzip: No match.
f2c: No such file or directory.
```

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

*FORTRAN 77 to C/C++ translator* is already packaged in Ubuntu repositories as [`f2c` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=f2c).

You can install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install f2c
```

---

Note: develop new good habit - before trying to compile something manually visit http://packages.ubuntu.com and search for needed application here.

Comment: Or use `apt-cache search` as an alternative to browser-based search.

Comment: how to search the file like /usr/local/bin/f2c
/usr/local/include/f2c.h
/usr/local/lib/libf2c.a
/usr/local/man/man1/f2c.1t
/usr/local/bin/f77 after the installation ?

Comment: You should find such files with `find /usr/local -type f -name *f2c*` and then remove them by hand from Midnight Commander (`mc`) or by graphical file-manager started as *root* user. If you want to list files installed with `f2c` package - use `dpkg -L f2c`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install curl:

```
sudo apt install curl
```

But it is better to use the Ubuntu rep and install with:

```
sudo apt-get install f2c
```

as N0rbert  [posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077153/790920).